# When using ods excel statement stop Excel converting numbers saved as character

Tags: excel, sas

I need to export some results from SAS to Excel. So far, I was using a simple `proc export` for that but since the export got more complex (multiple `proc result`s and `data sets` need to be mapped to one sheet) I need to find an alternative. 
It seems,`ods excel` is the way to go - and I agree, it is highly customizable - but I am facing a problem where I am not sure whether it is SAS or Excel related.

**Problem:**

When I have a SAS data set with character columns, where the data are strings of digits separated by points the `ods export` to Excel will always convert this data to a number format and which basically makes the data unreadable. For example:

```
character in SAS "04.2000" will become "4,2" in Excel (Standard format)
```

MWE:

```
data test;
input date $;
datalines;
04.2000
10.2001
; 

ods excel file="date.xlsx";
proc print data=test;
run;
ods excel close;
```

The proc export prints this data correctly, without automatic conversion. Is this something on the SAS or rather Excel side? What can I do to get the same result as in `proc export` when using `ods excel`, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To absolutely force the `<month>.<year>` date representation value to be a string in Excel you render it as a formula.  The value will not change, even after 'null' editing the cell (F2,Enter).

Example:

```
data test;
input datestring $;
forcedate = '="' || datestring || '"';
datalines;
04.2000
10.2001
; 

ods excel file="date.xlsx";
proc print data=test;
run;
ods excel close;
```

[image]

You can apply a `$CHAR<n>` format to your date string.  The field will still be interpreted as a number in Excel if you manually edit the cell.

Example:

```
data test;
input datestring $;
format datestring $char7.;
datalines;
04.2000
10.2001
; 

ods excel file="date.xlsx";
proc print data=test;
run;
ods excel close;
```

Excel (image)

[image]

You can also use the ODS EXCEL style option `tagattr='type:String'` to force the initial cell rendering, however upon editing (F2, Enter) Excel will again numerize the cell value.

Example:

```
proc print data=test;
  var datestring / style=[tagattr='type:text'];

* String also works;
* var datestring / style=[tagattr='type:String'];
run;
```

Comment: Nice, this works (guess the SAS format will just do fine for now)! But you are not aware of any possibility to tell Excel this is ``Text format`` to prevent automatic cell rendering (i know in proc export this also doesn't work though)? I read about the ``tagattr`` style option but got lost in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use format. it's work fine:

```
data test;
input date $;
datalines;
04.2000
10.2001
; 
run;
ods excel file="c:\temp\date.xlsx";
proc print data=test;
format date $20.;
run;
ods excel close;
```

Comment: Thx, Richard already mentioned this - and indeed, this works as long there is no cell rendering in Excel. So I really wonder how to tell Excel that the cell format is "text"...

Answer (score 1):

If you use PROC REPORT you can likely do this through your DEFINE statement.

```
define date/ 'Date' format = $20.  style(column)=[tagattr="type:text"];
```

Comment: I can confirm: the exact same behaviour as in ``proc print var datestring / style=[tagattr='type:text'];`` -- which means cell rendering will also revert the format

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Excel shows the same behaviour as Richard already described in his answer: it means, that the excel sheet will look just fine with ``04.2000`` format and the small indicator which says something like ``number as text formatted`` but as soon as one accesses the cell the cell will auto-render (F2 has the same effect) and the cell output will be different, in this example on my PC ``42.000``

Comment: Try adding the backtick to your text string as a formula, then. `=\`04.2000`

Comment: Editing the string to ``=`04.2000`` doesn't to the trick for me, it somehow renders the Excel file unreadable. Which works for me though is (as Richard suggested) to edit it like ``="04.2000"``

Comment: If you have a solution, please mark this as solved with the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Reeza. Hard coding it to a SAS dataset is ofc not ideal, but it seems there really is no better working workaround for this at the moment...

Comment: This isn't a SAS issue exactly though, it's an Excel issue. The data is being sent over correctly, Excel automatic type detection is the issue, which can also be turned off by the way.

Comment: Well, it’s kind of both: a SAS issue since there isn’t a way for me fix the format of the cell to "text" (the cell format remains standard no matter what) and an Excel issue for just being Excel where I can’t stop cell auto rendering...hence I also tagged both